# How to change the font of an input?

Tags: javascript, css, input, toggle, font-face

I need to toggle the font of an input tag with a checkbox, I tried using javascript and @font-face for this.

html:

```
<form action="#" method="post">

<input id="comment-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Press enter to post comment">                  

<span class="input-group-addon sinhala">
Sinhala 
<input type="checkbox" aria-label="..." value="si" id="sinhala-toggle-checkbox">
</span>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Mark as read">Post</button>

</form>

<script>
$("#sinhala-toggle-checkbox").click(function(){
$("#comment-input").toggleClass("sinhala");
});
</script>
```

css:

```
@font-face {font-family: sinhala;
  src: url("malithi_web.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.sinhala[type='text']{
    font-family: "Malithi web" !important;
    font-size:16px;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: only the font size changes, not the font

Comment: btw i was trying to load the font(custom) from the server it self

Comment: do you think that there is a problem in my browser/pc?? i even tried disabling direct-write on chrome.

Comment: thanx guys, tried a font that is not unicode, and that worked with all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your new font in different class. Then toggle this class.

```
    .newFontClass{
      font-family: "Some-New-Font" !important;
    }

    $("#sinhala-toggle-checkbox").click(function(){    
       if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
          $("#comment-input").addClass("newFontClass");
       }else{
         $("#comment-input").removeClass("newFontClass");
      }
   });
```

Comment: tried it, bt still not changing font.
maybe because the font is unicode?

Comment: thanx guys, tried a font that is not unicode, and that worked with all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you add correct jQuery CDN in your code:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If CDN is correct then just replace the script I post with your :-

**SCRIPT :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#sinhala-toggle-checkbox").click(function(){
     $("#comment-input").toggleClass("sinhala");
   });
});
```

Remaining whole code is correct.

Comment: If you can't edit the code, then how you correct the code. The code I posted is the solution for problem.

Comment: I mean to say code is fine, you just have to add the script I posted in the code.

Comment: tried it, bt still not changing font. maybe because the font is unicode?

Comment: everything (font-color, word spacing) changes except the font

Comment: thanx guys, tried a font that is not unicode, and that worked with all the suggestions.